# Is this a valid binary mutex implementation?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

I'm not really sure if this types of questions are frowned upon here, but it *is* the first place I come for when I have a question in mind, so, here we go.

I have a `std::vector<T> v` that I use to store data. In thread `t1`, there is a data generator and data insertion can happen at any time. On the other hand, in thread `t2`, at arbitrary times, I need to search `v` and access and return an element from it. Deletions, swaps etc. are guaranteed to **not** happen on `v` until both `t1` and `t2` join on main thread.

Without any thread-safety measures, code exits with `SIGABRT`. I first used `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard` and succeeded, however the number of lock/unlocks are in millions and I wish to speed things up a bit. So I tried to implement the following system:

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <thread>

// Mutex-like thingy begin
class MyMutex
{
private:
  std::atomic<bool> modifyLockRequest;
  std::atomic<bool> accessLockRequest;
  std::atomic<bool> accessLock;

public:
  MyMutex() :
      modifyLockRequest(false),
      accessLockRequest(false),
      accessLock(false) {}

  void acquireModifyLock() {
    assert(!modifyLockRequest);
    modifyLockRequest = true;
    while( accessLockRequest && accessLock ) {
      std::this_thread::yield();
    }
  }

  void releaseModifyLock() {
    assert(modifyLockRequest);
    modifyLockRequest = false;
  }

  void acquireAccessLock() {
    assert(!accessLockRequest);
    accessLockRequest = true;
    while (modifyLockRequest) {
      std::this_thread::yield();
    }
    accessLock = true;
  }

  void releaseAccessLock() {
    assert(accessLockRequest);
    accessLock = false;
    accessLockRequest = false;
  }
};

MyMutex myMutex;
```

Then I use this by

```cpp
myMutex.acquireModifyLock();
// Do insertion/deletion etc. on `v`
myMutex.releaseModifyLock();
```

and

```cpp
myMutex.acquireAccessLock();
// Do stuff with `v[i]`
myMutex.releaseAccessLock();
```

My rationale was to have 2 Boolean flags to alert whichever thread is trying to get a lock, and to have a third flag to break off cases where the two threads try to acquire a lock at the same time.

This code seems to work well in about 1/8th time of `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard` duo, however, my question is, is this solution **guaranteed** to **always** work in my case where there is only 2 threads?

Comment: Looks good to me, FWIW, assuming just two threads and that each always acquires the same type of "lock".

Comment: The Above code does not seem to be thread safe in one case. In acquireModifyLock while condition should be( accessLockRequest || accessLock ).  
Reason is: say in one thread you called acquireAccessLock and reached at  line accessLock = true; 
At the same time other thread processing the acquireModifyLock while statement. That evaluates to false. that means you get access to both the locks.

Comment: Did you try comparing performance to `std::shared_mutex`? And how do you measure performance?

Comment: @VishalGupta The utility of `accessLock` is to break cases where both `while` statements are reached at the same time where both `acquire`s fall into an infinite loop, so that change would be breaking. How to solve the problem you point to, though, I'm not sure

Comment: @rustyx Tbh, no, I didn't. Though I do have only 2 threads and I need to have full ownership during this time, so `std::shared_mutex` would be superfluous? Regarding performance testing, `1u << 20` times, I `push_back()` `int 0`s to `v` in `t1` and increment a random available element in `t2`, after both I `std::this_thread::yield()`. Access from either thread is protected with `std::lock_guard` and `myMutex`s lock/unlocks which are located at the exact same locations. I time the duration between `t1` creation and `t2.join()`

Comment: Far as I can tell, you just want a [spin lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, thank you very much! I'll try it out and somehow close this question if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `std::atomic_flag` to implement a spin lock worked well for the last 3 months. Also, since my implementation didn't have an atomic test-and-set mechanism, I'd say, **NO**, it's not a valid (thread-safe) implementation. Thanks to Igor Tandetnik for his suggestion.